# What is the right way to repeat html controls with a delete

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make a repeater html textbox controls which will add another field under it with a delete btn. The "+add more" working fine but the delete btn also adding more controls under it.

I want to know the right way to achieve it.

```js
$(function() {

  $('.btn-add-phone').click(function() {
    var sInputGroupPhoneHtml = ('<div class="form-group form-group-options"><div class="input-group input-group-option col-xs-12"><input type="text" name="option[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" style="width:50%"><select class="form-control" style="width:50%"><option value="Work">Work</option><option value="Home">Home</option><option value="Mobile">Mobile</option><option value="Other">Other</option></select><span class="input-group-addon input-group-phone-remove text-left"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></span></div></div>');

    $(this).append(sInputGroupPhoneHtml);

  });

  $('.btn-add-email').click(function() {
    var sInputGroupEmailHtml = ('<div class="form-group form-group-options"><div class="input-group input-group-option col-xs-12"><input type="email" name="option[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" style="width:50%"><select class="form-control" style="width:50%"><option value="Work">Work</option><option value="Personal">Personal</option><option value="Other">Other</option></select><span class="input-group-addon input-group-email-remove text-left"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></span></div></div>');

    $(this).append(sInputGroupEmailHtml);

  });

  $('.input-group-email-remove').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });



  jQuery(".toggleControlsPhone a").click(function() {
    jQuery(".showPhoneControls").toggle();
  });

  jQuery(".toggleControlsEmail a").click(function() {
    jQuery(".showEmailControls").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
div.input-group-option:last-child input.form-control {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}

div.input-group-option span.input-group-addon-remove {
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.input-group-option {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" />

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="form-group" id="phoneAddMore">
  <label class="control-label">Phone</label>
  <div class="form-group form-group-options">
    <div class="input-group input-group-option col-xs-12">
      <input type="text" name="option[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" style="width:50%">
      <select class="form-control" style="width:50%">
        <option value="Work">Work</option>
        <option value="Home">Home</option>
        <option value="Mobile">Mobile</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <a hre="#" class="btn-add-phone">+ add more </a>
  </div>

  <div class="clearfix"></div>

</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2uqxav83/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two issues:

1. When you append `sInputGroupEmailHtml`, you're appending it to the `<a>` tag that was clicked. So, clicking anywhere inside those elements will [bubble up](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing) to the `<a>` tag and fire the event to add a new group. I've changed it to append to the `<a>` tag's parent `.form-group` (outside of and after the `<a>` tag), instead.
2. When you bind a click handler to `.input-group-email-remove`, that element does not yet exist in the DOM. (It's only added when you click the "Add More" button.) I've used [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to bind the handler to `#addPhoneMore` rather than the button itself, so that the handler will fire even on dynamically generated children. I'm also using [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the `.form-group` of the clicked button. See [Event binding on dynamically created elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements).

```js
$(function() {

  $('.btn-add-phone').click(function() {
  
    var sInputGroupPhoneHtml = ('<div class="form-group form-group-options"><div class="input-group input-group-option col-xs-12"><input type="text" name="option[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" style="width:50%"><select class="form-control" style="width:50%"><option value="Work">Work</option><option value="Home">Home</option><option value="Mobile">Mobile</option><option value="Other">Other</option></select><span class="input-group-addon input-group-phone-remove text-left"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></span></div></div>');

    $(this).parent().append(sInputGroupPhoneHtml);

  });

  $('#phoneAddMore').on('click', '.input-group-phone-remove', function() {
    $(this).closest('.form-group').remove();
  });

});
```

```css
div.input-group-option:last-child input.form-control {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}

div.input-group-option span.input-group-addon-remove {
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.input-group-option {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="form-group" id="phoneAddMore">
  <label class="control-label">Phone</label>
  <div class="form-group form-group-options">
    <div class="input-group input-group-option col-xs-12">
      <input type="text" name="option[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" style="width:50%">
      <select class="form-control" style="width:50%">
        <option value="Work">Work</option>
        <option value="Home">Home</option>
        <option value="Mobile">Mobile</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <a hre="#" class="btn-add-phone">+ add more </a>
  </div>

  <div class="clearfix"></div>

</div>
```